# Reuse working set dialog?

Tags: eclipse

I want to create a new dialog looking like the Eclipse "Edit working set" dialog, example:

[image] (it's not that exact dialog, but it has the same look).

Since it seems to be a fairly standard type of dialog, I was hoping I would be able to reuse it, but I haven't found anything usable. The best I got was the actual code for the working set dialog in `package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.workingsets`, [see here](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/workingsets/JavaWorkingSetPage.java.html), which would atleast make it possible to "copy-and-paste" reuse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a more current version of [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.workingsets.JavaWorkingSetPage`](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/IDE-Eclipse/jdt/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/workingsets/JavaWorkingSetPage.java.htm) depends from [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.workingsets.AbstractWorkingSetWizardPage`](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/IDE-Eclipse/jdt/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/workingsets/AbstractWorkingSetWizardPage.java.htm).

That is the class you want to "emulate" (i.e. copy) in your own project, since it is an abstract class easier to reuse fro different "left" and "right" content.

Seen in Eclipse Helios:

[image]

It (the abstract class `AbstractWorkingSetWizardPage`) only depends on "generic" (i.e. "non-internal") classes:

- `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage`
- `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.IWorkingSetPage`

I am not aware of a more generic class outside of `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.workingsets`.